# Rotate camera around object with mouse Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, rotation

I want to move camera around gameobject, in other words: When I am holding mouse middle button and I am moving mouse, Camera should move around this gameobject, (like planet Earth around Sun but on y axis aswell) I have this code, but it's  doing strange things:

```
 private void RotateCamera()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse2))
    {

        yaw += _horizontalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"); //Horizontal speed and vertical are both equal 10, It's just how fast camera should move
        pitch += _verticalSpeed * -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        pitch = ClampAngle(pitch, -90, 90);
        transform.position = new Vector3(pitch + target.position.x, yaw + target.position.y, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply add an empty object at the location that you want to observe and add the camera as a child to it.

Then you can apply the rotation to the parent object and the camera should rotate around its parent and always be facing towards it.

If you want to change the target, simply remove the parent child hierarchy, move change the position of the former parent to the new location, rotate the camera to it (with `transform.LookAt()`) and set the parent-child hierarchy again like you did before.